# Interfacing RFID and atmega8

Tags: avr

I'm very new to avr microcontrollers, I want to interface RFID with atmega8, I have searched a lot about this but I didn't understand what to do. I want to know how to program it.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Typically this would involve: 1. Selecting a RFID module depending on the Tag-Types you want to read 2. Interface the RFID module with the Controller (typically USART) 3. Implement the communication protocol as required (read Tag, read/write data...). Step 2. and 3. require a good amount of basic knowledge, so it depends on your skill set where you have to start learning.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Arduino + any RFID module.
2. You can make [a ready](http://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=148455) circuit board 125 kHz RFID Tag Reader on the ATtiny13 (for example).
3. You can [buy](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-Pro-Mini-improved-version-ATmega168-AVR-core-board-development-board-Electronic-Component/1000001635472.html?spm=2114.30010308.3.354.JGUpeS&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10060_10061_10062_10056_10055_10037_10054_10033_10059_10032_10099_10078_10079_10077_426_10073_10102_10096_10052_10050_425_10051,searchweb201603_1&btsid=bd91cb7b-1929-4b91-8b59-7ada075af3d3) (or make own) AVR development board and USB-ISP programmer for AVR, take any RFID module, find RFID library and make own AVR-RFID device.